# SSIS Handling Extenal Issues

Tags: ssis, error-handling, external-process

I have an SSIS package that works fine. The package runs every night and takes about 4 hours to complete. I have am a newb to SSIS, so I want to see what my options are. I am not finding anything on the web about these two issues, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

1. What to do when I have an external
   issue such as a power
   failure/accidental restart. Is there
   a way to alert someone or have the
   package begin again on restart.
2. A couple weeks ago there was a
   process that got hung and locked
   table, making the process not
   execute. How is the best way to
   handle ensuring I have the proper
   access before starting and if not,
   get the access. I am ok with killing
   the processes etc.

Looking for best practice info. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 - there is no inherent "restart" mechanism in SSIS, since to start with, there is no inherent "start" mechanism.  You'll have to look at the process that you've got managing the scheduled execution of your packages, which I assume could be SQL Agent.
Given that, your options for determining if a SQL Agent job failed, and/or restarting that job are the same whether the contents of the job are SSIS packages or not.  There are quite a few stored procedures for monitoring and querying job execution and results.  You could also implement your own mechanism for recording job/package status.
SSIS does offer "checkpoints" to help you restart packages from certain points, but the general concensus on that feature is that it is limited in it's applicability - your mileage may vary.
Personally, I always include a failure route in my job to email someone on failure of the job, and configure my jobs and packages to be idempotent - that is, they can be re-run without fear of improperly conducting the same operations twice.  They either "reset" the environment (delete and reload), or they can detect exactly where they left off.

Item #2 is a difficult question and depends greatly on your environment and scenario.  You can use simple Tasks like an Execute SQL Task to run "test" commands that are tested to fail if sufficient privileges or locks exist.  Or you may be able to inquire directly through SPs or other mechanisms to determine if you need to take remedial action before you attempt to run the meat of your package.
Using Precedence Constraints "on failure" can assist with that kind of logic.  So can Event Handlers.